# MenuItem.Click RoutedEvent not firing in WPF

Tags: wpf, menuitem, routed-events

I have a `ContextMenu` on a `DataGrid` and I'm trying to capture the `MenuItem.Click` event for all the menu items. Like so:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridMembers" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="15"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MemberList}" RowHeaderWidth="5"
          MouseDoubleClick="dataGridMembers_MouseDoubleClick"
          MenuItem.Click="NewReservationContextMenuClick">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="GridMenu">
            <MenuItem 
                Name="AddSponsoredSingle"
                Header="Add Sponsored Single" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem 
                Name="EditNote"
                Header="Add/Edit Note" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem 
                Name="AddMale"
                Header="Add Male" />
            <MenuItem 
                Name="AddFemale"
                Header="Add Female"/>
            <MenuItem 
                Name="AddCouple"
                Header="Add Couple"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
     ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is the event never fires. `MenuItem.Click` is supposed to be a bubbled event and I should be able to catch it anywhere in the visual tree.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: adding the handler in code works fine. The following line in the constructor of the `.xaml.cs` and all is good.

```
GridMenu.AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(NewReservationContextMenuClick));
```

Comment: Note that in code you add handler to ContextMenu itself, not DataGrid. So the behavior is not different

Comment: First find that whether Menuitem is in VisualTree from DataGrid... If it is there it should fire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` is opened in a `Popup` control, which is not part of the visual tree of its logical parent.

In order to have a common `Click` handler for all `MenuItems`, move the handler to the `ContextMenu` element:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridMembers" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MemberList}" RowHeaderWidth="5" 
          MouseDoubleClick="dataGridMembers_MouseDoubleClick" 
          > 
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu> 
        <ContextMenu Name="GridMenu"
             MenuItem.Click="NewReservationContextMenuClick"> 
            ...
        </ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a style for all `MenuItem`s to assign the event handler:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="NewReservationContextMenuClick" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```